# Why would returning one line from a view be slower thant returning the whole view?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a view that returns the full dataset (6k rows) in less than a second. When I add a where statement, it takes more thant 2 minutes.

```
select * from myview
-- takes 1s

select * from myview where societe = 12345
-- takes 2mim 20s
```

What can be the reason ?
How can I force SQL server to calculate the whole view and choose the row afterwards ?

Comment: 1. SQL Server 2000? Really?? 2. Examine execution plans, something smells fishy...

Comment: Are stats on the underlying tables up-to-date?  Make sure appropriate indexes exist to support `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: Is there an index on "societe"?

Comment: @matt : Yes there is. But this is not the issue, if I force to use the index or not, the time used is the same.

Comment: @DanGuzman As far as I could the indexes are there.

Comment: @Amit Yes unfortunately it is a legacy application written in Access 97 that uses Server SQL 2000 :(  And I think it is fishy. I opted for a quick and dirty solution: Strip down the query and return defaults instead of the real calculated values. This will save 30 minutes a day for each employee, but will loose some expensive precision.

Comment: Please provide the DDL of the view and tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can create  **indexed views** in SQL Server - Please refer bellow links.

- [Indexed View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx)
- [Improving Performance with Indexed Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28SQL.100%29.aspx)

Steps you need to follows are:

- create a regular view
- create a clustered index on that view

and you're done!

This will increase performance, hope this helps.